# Change the bootstrap 4 dashboard example to fixed width sidebar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I know Bootstrap's grid is meant to be responsive, but for my application a fixed width sidebar makes more sense. Is there a painless way to change the example found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/dashboard/ to a fixed width sidebar of 300px or so?

I tried setting the min-width and max-width but it messes up the content of the main area. Should I not even be bothering with the grid system to accomplish this?

Comment: do you want something like this? https://www.atlascode.com/blog/bootstrap-fixed-width-sidebars/

Comment: Wow I think thats perfect! Thanks!